# query on calculating the Calendar day

Tags: c#

Can we use Calendar rule while getting Day of year in Gregorian calendar like we have for Week of year - GetWeekInYear(DateTime date, Calendar rule, DayOfweek firstDayOfWeek) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `GregorianCalendar.GetDayOfYear(DateTime time)`.

I am not aware of any culturally varying rules for calculating the day of the year.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to count the days starting at the first day of the first week of the year, where the first week of the year is determined according to a particular `CalendarWeekRule`, you could do something like this (illustrated as an extension method on the `GregorianCalendar` class:

```
public static class GregorianCalendarExtensions
{
    private const int DaysInWeek = 7;

    public static int GetDaysFromStartOfFirstWeekOfYear(
        this GregorianCalendar calendar,
        DateTime time,
        CalendarWeekRule rule,
        DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
    {
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);

        // Calculate 0-index day of week relative to first day of week.
        int completedDaysInWeek =
            ((int)dayOfWeek + DaysInWeek - (int)firstDayOfWeek) % DaysInWeek;

        // Decrement week of year by 1 to give count of completed weeks.
        int completedWeeksInYear =
            calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, rule, firstDayOfWeek) - 1;

        // Increment by one to start counting from 1 rather than 0.
        return (completedWeeksInYear * DaysInWeek) + completedDaysInWeek + 1;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        DateTime jan01;
        DateTime.TryParse("1/1/2011", out jan01);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            DateTime date = jan01 + TimeSpan.FromDays(i);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "{2} {0} is day {1} of year.",
                date.ToShortDateString(),
                cal.GetDaysFromStartOfFirstWeekOfYear(
                    date,
                    CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek,
                    DayOfWeek.Sunday),
                cal.GetDayOfWeek(date));
        }
```

Comment: How would those go into what day of the year it is?  If the year starts on a Monday is the 10th day of the year different than a year that starts on a Friday?

Answer (score 0):

With the Calendar class? A quick check of the MSDN documentation seems to imply that it does not have a method that gives you what you want directly.

However, it would be possible to write a method that does as much by combining the Calendar class with the DateTime class.

Comment: Relatively easy if you've ever played around with timestamps or datetimes in any other language. Baptism by fire if you're just learning how to program.

Comment: And I am vaguely curious what kind of application you are writing that needs to make use of Calendar rules. :-p